# Custom object protected visibility failing JSON parser

Tags: apex, custom-object, json, deserialize, visibility

My custom object in a DE org with a namespace has its visibility set to protected:

**Only Apex code in the same namespace can see the type. The name of the type and the record are visible if they're referenced in a formula.**

In Apex when I serialize and then deserialize an instance of this object to an `SObject` or to the concrete object type itself I get an error.

First, the serialization (and deserialization into a map):

```
CustomObject__c record = [SELECT Id, Name FROM CustomObject__c LIMIT 1];
String serialized = JSON.serialize(record);

// serialized: {"attributes":{"type":"NS__CustomObject__c","url":"/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/NS__CustomObject__c/a0E3h000001ngFCEAX"},"Id":"a0E3h000001ngFCEAX","Name":"Test"}

Map<String, Object> recMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(serialized);
```

If I deserialize into an `SObject`:

```
(SObject)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(recMap), SObject.class);
```

I get:

> System.JSONException: Nested object for polymorphic foreign key must
> have an attributes field before any other fields.

If I deserialize into `CustomObject__c`:

```
(CustomObject__c)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(recMap), CustomObject__c.class);
```

I get:

> System.NoAccessException: Insufficient Privileges: You do not have the
> level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested.
> Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access
> is necessary.

Note, this issue happens only to protected custom objects, with "Only Apex" visibility. i.e. if you replace `CustomObject__c` with, for example, `Account` these errors go away. Needless to say, the above code is being executed with the admin profile in the same namespace. And it doesn't matter whether it's executed in a class or in the Exec Anon panel.

Seems like a bug?

Comment: What are you attempting to do, specifically? This feels like an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You should at least include the background of what you're attempting to do so we can provide an informed answer.